# how plot stack bar keeping order of the data Python

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, plotly-python, plotly-express

I have a df with 3 columns: "Day-Shift","State" and "Seconds". Need to visualize this data using stack bar chart but keeping data as it is.

Sample DF:

```
    Day-Shift   State          seconds
    Day 01-05   A              7439
    Day 01-05   STOPPED        0
    Day 01-05   B              10
    Day 01-05   C              35751
    Night 01-05 C              43200
    Day 01-06   STOPPED        7198
    Day 01-06   F              18
    Day 01-06   A              14
    Day 01-06   A              29301
    Day 01-06   STOPPED        6
    Day 01-06   A              6663
    Night 01-06 A              43200
```

Chart X-axis: "Day-shift",Y:"seconds",color:"State""

Ex: in Day 01-05 need to plot this same as in this df's order(first state A and stoped and B and finally state C).
I plotted this using python plotly but chart **always keeps the same state to the bottom of the stack bar.** Is there any way to visualize the same data order as it is in python.

DF:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Day-Shift': {0: 'Day 01-05',
  1: 'Day 01-05',
  2: 'Day 01-05',
  3: 'Day 01-05',
  4: 'Night 01-05',
  5: 'Day 01-06',
  6: 'Day 01-06',
  7: 'Day 01-06',
  8: 'Day 01-06',
  9: 'Day 01-06',
  10: 'Day 01-06',
  11: 'Night 01-06',
  12: 'Day 01-07',
  13: 'Night 01-07',
  14: 'Night 01-07',
  15: 'Night 01-07',
  16: 'Night 01-07',
  17: 'Night 01-07',
  18: 'Night 01-08',
  19: 'Night 01-08',
  20: 'Night 01-08',
  21: 'Night 01-08',
  22: 'Day 01-08',
  23: 'Day 01-08',
  24: 'Day 01-08',
  25: 'Night 01-09',
  26: 'Night 01-09',
  27: 'Night 01-09',
  28: 'Day 01-09',
  29: 'Day 01-09',
  30: 'Day 01-09',
  31: 'Day 01-09',
  32: 'Day 01-10',
  33: 'Night 01-10',
  34: 'Day 01-11',
  35: 'Day 01-11',
  36: 'Day 01-11',
  37: 'Day 01-11',
  38: 'Day 01-11',
  39: 'Night 01-11',
  40: 'Day 01-12',
  41: 'Night 01-12',
  42: 'Day 01-13',
  43: 'Day 01-13',
  44: 'Day 01-13',
  45: 'Day 01-13',
  46: 'Day 01-13',
  47: 'Day 01-13',
  48: 'Day 01-13',
  49: 'Night 01-13',
  50: 'Day 01-14',
  51: 'Day 01-14',
  52: 'Day 01-14',
  53: 'Day 01-14',
  54: 'Day 01-14',
  55: 'Day 01-14',
  56: 'Day 01-14',
  57: 'Day 01-14',
  58: 'Day 01-14',
  59: 'Night 01-14'},
 'State': {0: 'D',
  1: 'STOPPED',
  2: 'B',
  3: 'A',
  4: 'A',
  5: 'A',
  6: 'A1',
  7: 'A2',
  8: 'A3',
  9: 'A4',
  10: 'B1',
  11: 'B1',
  12: 'B1',
  13: 'B1',
  14: 'B2',
  15: 'STOPPED',
  16: 'RUNNING',
  17: 'B',
  18: 'STOPPED',
  19: 'B',
  20: 'RUNNING',
  21: 'D',
  22: 'STOPPED',
  23: 'B',
  24: 'RUNNING',
  25: 'STOPPED',
  26: 'RUNNING',
  27: 'B',
  28: 'RUNNING',
  29: 'STOPPED',
  30: 'B',
  31: 'D',
  32: 'B',
  33: 'B',
  34: 'B',
  35: 'RUNNING',
  36: 'STOPPED',
  37: 'D',
  38: 'A',
  39: 'A',
  40: 'A',
  41: 'A',
  42: 'A',
  43: 'A1',
  44: 'A2',
  45: 'A3',
  46: 'A4',
  47: 'B1',
  48: 'B2',
  49: 'B2',
  50: 'B2',
  51: 'B',
  52: 'STOPPED',
  53: 'A',
  54: 'A1',
  55: 'A2',
  56: 'A3',
  57: 'A4',
  58: 'B1',
  59: 'B1'},
 'seconds': {0: 7439,
  1: 0,
  2: 10,
  3: 35751,
  4: 43200,
  5: 7198,
  6: 18,
  7: 14,
  8: 29301,
  9: 6,
  10: 6663,
  11: 43200,
  12: 43200,
  13: 5339,
  14: 8217,
  15: 0,
  16: 4147,
  17: 1040,
  18: 24787,
  19: 1500,
  20: 14966,
  21: 1410,
  22: 2499,
  23: 1310,
  24: 39391,
  25: 3570,
  26: 17234,
  27: 47390,
  28: 36068,
  29: 270,
  30: 6842,
  31: 20,
  32: 43200,
  33: 43200,
  34: 2486,
  35: 8420,
  36: 870,
  37: 30,
  38: 31394,
  39: 43200,
  40: 43200,
  41: 43200,
  42: 36733,
  43: 23,
  44: 6,
  45: 4,
  46: 4,
  47: 3,
  48: 6427,
  49: 43200,
  50: 620,
  51: 0,
  52: 4,
  53: 41336,
  54: 4,
  55: 4,
  56: 4,
  57: 23,
  58: 1205,
  59: 43200}})
```

Plotly code:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.bar(df, x="Day-Shift", y="seconds", color="State")
fig.show()
```